# Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $(x)=0$ using formal definition

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I need to prove that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ using the formal definition of derivative and limit
$$
  f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2 \sin\left(\frac1x\right),&x\neq 0
\\
0,&x = 0
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: You just have to bound $|f(x)-f(0)|/|x|$ using that $|\sin y|\leq 1$. And then squeeze.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\; x\sin\frac{1}{x}=0$$

since $\,\sin\frac{1}{x}\,$ is bounded everywhere and thus also in any neighborhoof of zero.